# Amazon Product Advertising API sort all items based on price?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

Is there a way to sort all items based on price in Amazon Product Advertising API? 
It's possible in the website but don't know why the product listing scratchpad is saying it's a restricted combination. Any workaround ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can sort the data returned by the Amazon API using Php sort functions. For example ksort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Comment: No the API doesn't says it's restricted to search ALL category + sort based on PRICE